# Debugging import of cloud optimized GeoTIFFs into PostGIS

Tags: raster, postgis, gdal, raster2pgsql, cloud-optimized-geotiff

I have a fairly basic setup where an Apache web server is sitting alongside a PostGIS instance, all run and created together using docker compose.
I have a number of cloud optimized GeoTIFFs (COGs) that are available on the web server that I am trying to import into the database using the `-R` (out-db) switch in the `raster2pgsql` command.

The error I am getting is `ERROR: Unable to read raster file`

I think I have the URL to the raster correct since I can successfully run `gdalinfo` on it from within the PostGIS container:
`gdalinfo /vsicurl/http://apache-container/my-cog.tif`

Here is my full command that I run (the arg(`$1`) is the path to the GeoTIFF):

```
    file_url="/vsicurl/http://apache-container/$(basename $1)"
    table_name=$(basename $1 .tif)
    export PGPASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASS}
    raster2pgsql \
        -s 3857 \               # SRID of the data
        -t 256x256 \            # Tile raster
        -I \                    # Index the table
        -R \                    # Load as "out-db"
        $file_url \             # File to load
        $table_name \
        | psql -d mydb -U ${POSTGRES_USER} -p 5432 -h localhost
```

Do you have any advice on debugging `raster2pgsql` commands and what issues I might be overlooking here?

#### Update

I remove the line-continuations for simplicity sake:
`raster2pgsql -s 3857 -t 512x512 -I -R $file_url $table_name | psql -d mydb -U ${POSTGRES_USER} -p 5432 -h localhost`

And now I'm getting the error: `ERROR 5: Missing url parameter`
But, I can't find any info on this error.
Also, occasionally, this error: `Warning 1: HTTP response code on http: 0`

#### Settlement

One nice discovery is that if I manually run these commands on the Postgis container, it works fine (previously this script was part of a database init process). So maybe it's something with the docker startup and the GeoTIFFs not being available at the moment these commands need them??

Anyway, feel free to close this as I probably won't be spending too much more time debugging it now that I have a (more)work around, unless you think someone else would find the answer useful.